# How to validate an XML document against a schema in a Windows Store App?

Tags: xml, xsd, windows-runtime

I am trying to figure out how I could validate an XML document when reading it against a XML Schema in a Windows Store app.

With the full .NET API I can use ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema on a XmlReaderSettings instance that is passed to an XmlReader and add Schemas using Schemas.Add. Unfortunately in the .NET API for Windows Store Apps XmlReaderSettings does neither have a ValidationType property nor a Schemas property.

Using XElement I could use the extension method Validate and an XmlSchemaSet in full .NET but both are also not available in the .NET API for Windows Store Apps.

Did not find anything related to Schemas in the XmlDocument class either (found 
XmlLoadSettings.ValidateOnParse but according to the documentation this is for DTDs).

So: How could I validate an XML document against a Schema in WinRT or with the .NET API for Windows Store Apps? Or was this feature simply forgotten by the WinRT team?

**Update:**

XML Schema seems not to be supported, according to an answer to a similar quetion on answers.flyppdevportal.com. See http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=b0df7a08-23c7-4adf-96c9-608d237cb024. It's hard to believe though. Did the WinRT team think XML validation is not important for Windows Store Apps?